# Проблемы с jdk и NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, java

Здравствуйте!
После переустановки jdk при запуске стал ругаться NetBeans. Пишет, что

> "Cannot locate java installation in
> specified jdkhome C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_05 Do you want to
> try to use default version ?"

У меня стоит jdk1.8.0_25. Почему он хочет устаревший jdk? Как исправить проблему?

Comment: Гуглить пробовали?
https://www.google.ru/#newwindow=1&q=Cannot%20locate%20java%20installation%20in%20specified%20jdkhome%20netbeans

Comment: @andreyqin, я не написал бы сюда, если б нашел в гугле. Там везде пишут, что нужно прописать правильный путь в файле. Он у меня верный. Странно то, что он требует jdk старой версии, об этом я написал в вопросе.

Comment: @compl, По возможности публикуйте ответы на форуме, они могут помочь многим в будущем.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Решение 1**

Откройте свою папку NetBeans и найдите там файл:

```
C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.x\etc\netbeans.conf
```

Найдите следующею строчку и измените на свой путь к Java:

```
netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7xxxxx"
```

Вам потребуются права администратора, чтобы отредактировать файл: netbeans.conf

На stackoverflow людям помогло решить поставленную Вами задачу.

**Решение 2**

Также там пишут, что можно зайти в "Сервис\Tools -> Платформы Java\Platforms Java -> Добавить платформу \ Add platform -> Указать папку с Java".

**Решение 3**

Запустить исполняемый файл netbeans со следующими параметрами (естественно, свой путь в кавычках пропишите):

```
--jdkhome "C:\Program Files\jdk1.6.0_20"
```

Comment: Проблема уже решена.

Answer (score 0):

Система мне упорно не разрешала редактировать файл `\netbeans.conf` и провозившись около часа, просто решила дать программе то, чего она хочет.

Установила `Java` по тому адресу, по которому ее искал `NetBeans` (естественно, более новую версию), изменив имя папки на то, которое требовал `NetBeans`. После этого все запустилось.